# Can an ideal fluid undergoes a turbulent flow?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, flow, viscosity, turbulence, vortex

[image]

I have read before that the existence of viscosity is the main reason for the appearance of vortex. However, by definition, an ideal fluid has $\eta=0$. So, can an ideal fluid undergo a turbulent motion?

Comment: What kind of "a turbulent motion" do you have in mind?

Comment: When vortex form

Answer (score 1):

Turbulent behavior is mainly caused by nonlinear effects. Let's recall the Naiver-Stokes equation:
$$\partial_t \vec{v}+\vec{v}.\vec{\nabla}\vec{v}= -\frac{1}{\rho}\vec{\nabla}p+\nu \nabla^ 2 \vec{v}$$
Now let's estimate the order of magnitude of the ratio of the nonlinear term to the viscose term
$$\mathcal{O}\bigg(\frac{\vec{v}.\vec{\nabla}\vec{v}}{\nu \nabla^2 \vec{v}}\bigg)\sim \frac{v\frac{v}{l}}{\nu \frac{v}{l^2}}\sim \frac{v\,l}{\nu}$$
where $v$ is the average flow speed in the system and $l$ is the typical size of the system. The result is simply the **Reynolds number** $R_e$.

On the other hand, experimental data show that when $R_e$ increases, there is a system-specific critical value for Reynolds number, i.e.; $R_{cr}$, beyond which the flow becomes turbulent: $R_e>R_{cr}$. This means that viscosity alone does not determine whether a flow is turbulent or not. You need to know the $R_e$ of the flow.

Ironically, the smaller the viscosity, the larger $R_e$ and the flow will be  more unstable.

See also Landau-Lifshitz Vol 6 section 26.

Hope this helps.